# Is jGrowl covering my elements after it fades out?

Tags: jquery, jgrowl

I am using jGrowl to show a message on the screen. It looks great. However, after the message has faded out, the jGrowl div is still covering those elements that are under it, so they are not clickable!

This is extra noticable in my case, because I edited the styles to ensure the message is shown in the center-center of the screen.

```
div.jGrowl.center {
    height:             50%;
    top:                25%;
    width:              50%;
    left:               25%;
}
```

Can it really be true that a plugin like jGrowl, used by so many people, has this problem? Or is it perhaps because I'm doing something wrong.

I checked with "Inspect element" in Chrome, and sure enough, this is the element that is covering the other elements on my page:

```
<div id="jGrowl" class="center jGrowl">
<div class="jGrowl-notification"></div>
</div>
```

UPDATE - Here is the solution:

```
$("#jGrowl").show();
$.jGrowl("my message", {
    beforeClose: function(e,m) {
        $("#jGrowl").hide();
    }
});
```

ELABORATION - After trying different things, I find that the below is the best solution. Add a default setting for these events when the page loads:

```
$(function () {
    $.jGrowl.defaults.beforeOpen = function(e,m) { $("#jGrowl").show(); };
    $.jGrowl.defaults.close = function(e,m) { $("#jGrowl").hide(); };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with jGrowl but could you check to make sure that the "close" event is firing?

jGrowl comes with the ability to "close" the window right, with an "X" in the corner?  If you implement that and click the "x" - are you able to then click on the items that were covered?

Comment: I put some 'hide' code in the close event and put some 'show' code just before showing the message - it works, although it's not pretty.

Answer (score 0):

There is no div covering everything after it fades out in my browser, Chrome 12.0.742.16. Chances are you're doing something wrong but without a test case I couldn't say what.

Comment: It's not covering 'everything' - it's only covering the area that it was covering while showing the message and a little area around it.

Comment: Yep that's what I meant, there's nothing covering it in my tests.

Comment: Strange - I must be doing something different then. Oh well, I have elaborated my question with the solution for anyone else that somehow bumps into the same quirk as I.